# How do I add a new line without deleting text in a RichTextBox and change it's colour in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, colors, richtextbox

I can't seem to find the answer anyway. But my Question is;

In visual basic I want to make something called a problem panel and to test it I am making a debug. It uses a progress bar and timer. Here is some of the code so far.

```
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 1 Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = "A developer debug has been executed, please wait"
    End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 3 Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length + 1
        RichTextBox1.Text &= "."
    End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 5 Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length + 1
        RichTextBox1.Text &= "."
    End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 7 Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length + 1
        RichTextBox1.Text &= "."
    End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 10 Then
        RichTextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "Testing Warnings"
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow
    End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 15 Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow
        RichTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Warning"
    End If
```

Basically all it does is create a line, adds a new one and continues typing text. But I can't get it to add a new line. Print 'Warnings' and change that text to Yellow. But using all the code on the internet it stays white?

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

If it's not clear let me summarize:

*Print's text and keeps everything white.

*Prints a new line with everything staying in the RichTextBox.

*The Text will say, Critical, Warning, Information, etc.

*And It needs to change the colour of the text but not change all of the other printed text colour.

Thanks in advance

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba; pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a subroutine that will help you:

```
Private Sub AppendTextWithColor(rich_text_box As RichTextBox, color As Color, text As String)
    Dim length_before = rich_text_box.TextLength

    rich_text_box.AppendText(text)

    Dim length_after = rich_text_box.TextLength

    rich_text_box.SelectionStart = length_before
    rich_text_box.SelectionLength = length_after - length_before
    rich_text_box.SelectionColor = color
End Sub
```

It allows you to append some text to the RichTextBox with a specific color.

You can use it like this:

```
AppendTextWithColor(RichTextBox1, Color.Yellow, Environment.NewLine + "Warning")
```

It works by recording the length of the RichTextBox's text before and after appending the new text. It then sets the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` based on the recorded lengths to select the appended text. It then changes the color of the selected text using the `SelectionColor` property.